# Convert a VBScript to C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, ms-access-2003

Can some one help me converting this script to C# I am still very much a begiiner and learning in C#. The script uses OpenCurrentDatabase to open (and keep open) an Access .mdb file, I must use this method and the code as it is but converted to C#, any help would be very much appreciated.

I’m using notepad to edit the cs file and csc.exe to compile it (I don’t have any other C# tools).

```
dim fso    
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dim filePath
filePath = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
filePath = filePath & "\test.mdb"
'WScript.Echo filePath

If (fso.FileExists(filePath)) Then
    dim appAccess
    set appAccess = createObject("Access.Application")
    appAccess.visible = true
    appAccess.UserControl = true 'To leave the application open after the script completes you need to set the UserControl property to true.
    appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase filePath, True, "mypassword"
Else
    WScript.Echo "File doesn’t exist"
End If
```

Comment: Do you need to open the database so that a user can access it manually, or are you going to insert/query programatically (using C#)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your VBScript saved somewhere you can call it from within C# with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"P:\ath\to\Script.vbs");
```

If you just need to open a connection to the database:

```
// Declare the path to the database file
var filePath = @"Path\to\database.accdb";

// If statement using File.Exists()
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{ 
    // Create new OleDbConnection object and call Open()
    var conn = new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={filePath}");
    conn.Open();
}
else
{
    // Write to the console if the file does not exist
    Console.WriteLine("The file does not exist");
}
```

You will need to reference `System.Data.OleDb` to use `OleDbConnection`, and `System.IO` for `File.Exists()`

Hope this helps

Comment: Bassie, Open the actual database (not a connection), and I need OpenCurrentDatabase because I pass a Database password. Surely a simple C# script can achieve this without my having to install other programs. Can references not be avoided by using Late Dynamic Binding?

Comment: Bassie can I add my vbscript lines into code like below ? I get gui errors won't compile ? how  would this be done?

Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "vbscript";
string vbscript = "msgbox(\"test\")";
obj.Eval(vbscript);

Comment: @pdeman I edited my answer at the top - does that help? With this you can run your VBScript as is from within the cs file. You can also add arguments to it from here if you need to