# How to Format VBScript String Executed Dynamically Through C#

Tags: c#, vbscript

The code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659495/how-to-embed-vbs-in-c-sharp-and-run-it) works fine as below:

```
var scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "vbscript";
var vbscript = @"MsgBox(""Hello"");
obj.Eval(vbscript);
```

But as soon I try to add another line to the script, for example:

```
var vbscript = @"MsgBox(""Hello"")
                 MsgBox(""World"")";
```

I get a syntax error when calling `obj.Eval(vbsbcript)`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Dynamic.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error

I can see that the value of `vbscript` contains a load of `\r\n`s for the newlines:

```
"MsgBox(\"Hello\")\r\nMsgBox(\"World\")"
```

I tried declaring it with

```
vbscript = "MsgBox(\"Hello\")" +
            Environment.NewLine +
            "MsgBox(\"World\")";
```

but with the same results.

Is it possible to run some vbscript stored in a string which contains multiple lines in C#? If so how can this be achieved?

I know it is possible by calling a `.vbs` file with `Process.Start(path)`, but can it be done directly from a string in the progam without having to depend on another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the

```
var vbscript = @"MsgBox(""Hello"")
                 MsgBox(""World"")";
```

Try to add this

```
vbscript = vbscript.Replace("\r\n", " & VbCrLf & ");
```

That should do it.

From [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbcrlf(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a carriage-return character combined with a linefeed
>   character for print and display functions.

Comment: Thanks Juan, that did it for my example. I am now seeing the same `syntax error` when I try running theh one-line script `Dim test`. Do you know why thi might be?

Comment: could you share the full script you want to run?

Comment: the full script is actually from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42610844/convert-a-vbscript-to-c-sharp/  But even trying to run just the 1 line `Dim test` saved in a string as above produces the syntax error.